# What happens to fstream object when underlying file is unlinked?

Tags: c++, fstream

I have following code opening a stream and writing to it and then removing it, again trying to write it.
Is there a way to get fstream object get notified of non existent file and recreate file (i know i can use stat to check but i am wondering if there is a state change in stream object itself)

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::fstream
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int main () {
std::fstream fs;
fs.open ("test.txt",std::fstream::out);
if (fs.is_open())
{
    fs << "lorem ipsum";
    std::cout << "Operation successfully performed\n";
    std::cout<<fs.fail()<<std::endl;
    unlink("test.txt");
    fs << "more lorem ipsum";
    fs.write("hi",2);
    fs.write("hi",2);
    fs.write("hi",2);
    fs.write("hi",2);
    fs.write("hi",2);
    std::cout<<fs.fail()<<std::endl;
    fs.close();
}
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening file";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried

```
is_open()
good()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing. The I/O continues to the unlinked file, which disappears when all open FDs to it have been closed.

Comment: That's actually a sad thing happening on Unix systems

Comment: @PaulStelian That's actually a consequence of 'names don't have files: files have names' [Dennis Ritchie, or possibly Ken Thompson, *c.* 1974].

Comment: Nice quote there! That said, *is* there a way to do what the OP wants? (recreate the file if missing, in a reliable way)

Comment: I think i will end up using stat/access. anyways @EJP your mention was nice. I'll lookup that quote.